# Why do ferromagnetic materials increase inductance

Tags: inductance, ferromagnetism

Why does adding a ferromagnetic core to a transformer coil (for example), increase it's inductance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inductance is proportional to the relative magnetic permeability of the material in the inductor. 
Ferromagnetic materials are known to have a relative magnetic permeability which is much much greater than the magnetic permeability of vacuum. Hence inserting a ferromagnetic material into the core of an inductor increases its inductance manifold.

Comment: So then, what is it about the structure of the ferromagnetic material which gives it high magnetic permeability?

Comment: Domains govern this stuff I suppose.